# Rails API endpoint: redirect_to url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

We're receiving a PUT call to an api endpoint (below) on our application for updating a record we've created, from a third party partner via an embedded iframe:

```
class Api::LineItemsController < Api::BaseController
  before_action :find_line_item

  def update 
    if params[:status] == "success"

      #update the giftcard object based on Jifiti's data payload
      @line_item.update_attributes(line_item_params)
      @line_item.save!

      @line_item.order.update_attributes! state: "complete", completed_at: Time.now, payment_state: 'paid'

      redirect_to "/orders/#{@line_item.order.number}"
    else
      render json: { message: "Uh Oh, there was a problem" }, status: 400
    end
  end
```

What is the correct convention for redirecting to a url after updating?  When I do this, it throws an InvalidAuthenticity Token error and doesn't redirect at all.

Comment: There is a lot of things wrong here. In an API response for an update request you don't redirect - you just send a 200 OK or 204 NO CONTENT response. You can optionally return JSON containing the updated entity. If its not valid you should return a 4xx response - Rails commonly uses 422 UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY

Comment: The InvalidAuthenticityToken error has nothing to do with the redirect. Rails by default requires an anti-csrf token to be included with the request. You can disable the CSRF protection by skipping the middleware or with `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token`.

Comment: There is also the issue that both  `save!` and `update_attributes!` will raise an exception if any of the validations fail. I can't see that you're rescueing the exception so it cause a 500 Internal Server response to be returned. There is also no reason why you should be sending two UPDATE queries here. Update once - and check that the operation is actually successful instead.

Comment: To elaborate on the first point. You don't redirect in an API.  You're thinking in terms of a classical web application. In an API you send a location header back for example when creating resources and then its up to the client if it wants to send a new request to get the resource. When updating the client already knows the location of the resource so the location header is kind of irrelevant unless updating the resource changes its location.

Comment: Okay, that all makes total sense.  But how would I handle a redirect after we respond with ```render json: { message: "you did it!" }, status: 200```?

Comment: You handle it in your client side JS in your ajax handler. If you want to do a "hard redirect" you set `window.location = some_url`.